# How to select an inter-year period with xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

The context: I have a netCDF with 30 years of (daily) data. I would like to select data across years for specific months, e.g. every May to March period.

I could do it with a separate function for selection, but I'm hoping there's a straightforward way to do it with xarray. The version I have installed is 0.9.6

Comment: What do you mean by "straightforward way"? I am thinking that `xarray` is not CDO or NCO, where you can just give an operator and you get a result what you want. With Python script, you have to work for your output - initialize new file with all necessary variables/dimensions, cut the data that you need, write selected data. Perhaps with cdo/nco you get what you want with much smaller effort.

Comment: "What do you mean by 'straightforward way' - One example would be the resample method (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html) which allows you to select samples across the time series over a variety of time frames - that's an example of a built-in method that could be used to simplify a common task. Now for what I'm after I could of course accomplish what I'm after using `apply` and my own function - I said as much in the body of my question. You're welcome to write an answer if you have any other suggestions than that approach.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your time dimension is a datetime object, you can use the [DatetimeAccessor](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html) object to select only the months you'd like:

```
# select only daily data from June, July, and August
da_jja_only = ds.sel(time=ds.time.dt.month.isin([6, 7, 8]))
```

Comment: I had to update to the latest version of xarray (0.10.9), but resolved my issue.

Comment: da_jja_only = ds.sel(datetime=ds.datetime.dt.month.isin([6, 7, 8])) works for me. Thanks for the clue!