# Fitering xarray.DataArray by month with multiple possible values

Tags: python-xarray

I want to filter a xarray DataArray to only keep the data where the month is part of some *month_list*.

Let's say I need april and june, my `month_list` would be `[4, 6]`.
Ideally I would like to do:

```
da.where(da.time.dt.month in month_list, drop=True)
```

But this throw an error (because of *in*):
*ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

So I came up with this solution:

```
def month_resampler(da: DataArray):
        acc = []
        for gr, val in da.groupby(da.time.dt.month):
            if gr in month_list:
                acc.append(val)
        return xarray.concat(acc, "time")
```

But it feels overkill to use groupby here. Especially I'm not sure what are the performance of groupby when working on large datasets.
I believe *sel* or *isel* would be better to filter elements but I can't find a way to use them properly.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.isin` to filter on a pre-defined list of months.

Example:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

# desired months
mon_list = [2, 3, 4, 8]

# before
print(np.unique(x.time.dt.month))

# [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]

xsel = x.sel(
    time=np.isin(x.time.dt.month, mon_list)
)

# after
print(np.unique(xsel.time.dt.month))

# [2 3 4 8]
```

Comment: I discovered that you can even do `da.sel(time=da.time.dt.month.isin(month_list))` from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533630/how-to-select-an-inter-year-period-with-xarray