# How to only select winter months of daily data in xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray, cdo-climate

I have gridded daily temperature data but am only interested in the winter months.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

#open NASA GISS gridded temperature netcdf file
df = xr.open_dataset('BerkeleyEarth.nc')

#pull out temperature variable
air=df.temperature

#select only winter months
WinterAir = air[(air.time.dt.month >= 12) | (air.time.dt.month <= 2)]
```

When I try to select the months this way I get the following error message:
AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'month'. How do I select only winter months?

Here is a screenshot of the netcdf file
[image]

Comment: Can you just use df.month

Comment: But how would I select the df.temperature values that correspond with the correct df.month values? I'm new to xarray and python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select an inter-year period with xarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533630/how-to-select-an-inter-year-period-with-xarray)

Comment: Note that this is not an exact duplicate of the linked question. In this question's case, the data is shaped oddly and does not have a datetime coordinate. The OP is asking about how to access the DatetimeAccessor attributes on a dataset without a time coordinates. Answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by:

```
# select only winter months

WinterAir = air[(df.month >= 12) | (df.month <= 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work for your data specifically is that you don't have a `datetime` coordinate `time`; instead, you have a dimension `time` without any coordinate data labeling it, and then you have data variables with a variety of date components. Because of this, you can reference the `month` data variable directly and use that to slice your data.

You could always construct a datetime coordinate using the day, month, and year values in your data and assign that as the `time` coordinate, and then the usual time series functionality built into xarray would work.

As an example, here's a dataset similar to yours in structure:

```py
In [6]: dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", freq="D")
   ...:
   ...: ds = xr.Dataset(
   ...:     coords={"lon": [-135, -45, 45, 135], "lat": [-45, 45]},
   ...:     data_vars={
   ...:         "day": (("time",), dates.day),
   ...:         "month": (("time",), dates.month),
   ...:         "year": (("time",), dates.year),
   ...:         "temperature": (
   ...:             ("lat", "lon", "time"),
   ...:             np.random.random(size=(2, 4, len(dates))),
   ...:         ),
   ...:     },
   ...: )

In [7]: ds
Out[7]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 366, lat: 2, lon: 4)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) int64 -135 -45 45 135
  * lat          (lat) int64 -45 45
Dimensions without coordinates: time
Data variables:
    day          (time) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
    month        (time) int64 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
    year         (time) int64 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 ... 2020 2020 2020 2020
    temperature  (lat, lon, time) float64 0.2308 0.3257 ... 0.3501 0.009162
```

Note that `time` is a special "dimension without coordinates" - this means that *there are no labels* on the time dimension, and xarray does not know anything about "time" except that it has a certain shape and is the dimension indexing several of your data variables. Importantly, in your data, `time` is not a datetime type.

Because `month` is a data variable in the dataset, you need to reference month directly, as you found, and the DatetimeAccessor `ds.time.dt` is not available:

```py
In [8]: ds.loc[{"time": ds.month == 2}]
Out[8]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 29, lat: 2, lon: 4)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) int64 -135 -45 45 135
  * lat          (lat) int64 -45 45
Dimensions without coordinates: time
Data variables:
    day          (time) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
    month        (time) int64 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ... 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
    year         (time) int64 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 ... 2020 2020 2020 2020
    temperature  (lat, lon, time) float64 0.2821 0.08776 0.2018 ... 0.929 0.4774
```

If the `time` dimension had a corresponding coordinate of type `datetime`, e.g. by assigning the previous `dates` array to the `time` coord, everything would work as you expect:

```py
In [10]: dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", freq="D")
    ...:
    ...: ds = xr.Dataset(
    ...:     coords={"lon": [-135, -45, 45, 135], "lat": [-45, 45], "time": dates},
    ...:     data_vars={
    ...:         "temperature": (
    ...:             ("lat", "lon", "time"),
    ...:             np.random.random(size=(2, 4, len(dates))),
    ...:         ),
    ...:     },
    ...: )

In [11]: ds
Out[11]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (lat: 2, lon: 4, time: 366)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) int64 -135 -45 45 135
  * lat          (lat) int64 -45 45
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 ... 2020-12-31
Data variables:
    temperature  (lat, lon, time) float64 0.09064 0.5252 ... 0.08733 0.6283
```

Now the xarray datetime accessors work the way you'd expect

```py
In [12]: ds.loc[{"time": ds.time.dt.month == 2}]
Out[12]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (lat: 2, lon: 4, time: 29)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) int64 -135 -45 45 135
  * lat          (lat) int64 -45 45
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-02-01 2020-02-02 ... 2020-02-29
Data variables:
    temperature  (lat, lon, time) float64 0.3407 0.6847 0.3073 ... 0.8578 0.1335
```

See xarray's docs on [Coordinates](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#coordinates) and [working with time series data](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! I am now trying to create a new xarray dataset with time as a coordinate. Here's what i have: `latitude=df.latitude
longitude=df.longitude
temperature=df.temperature
dates = pd.date_range("1950-01-01", "2021-12-31", freq="D")
NewBerkeley = xr.Dataset(
    coords={"lon": longitude, "lat": latitude, "time": dates},
    data_vars={"temperature":(( "lat", "lon","time"),temperature,),},)` but get the following error "ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 26298 on 'time' and length 360 on 'temperature'"

Comment: Conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 26298 on 'time' and length 360 on 'temperature' <-- it's telling you exactly what it sounds like. you need to make sure the `time` dim on temperature is the same length as the coordinate you're trying to assign.

Comment: oh - make sure that the dimensions of temperature are actually `(lat, lon, time)` and not some other ordering?